# Java, can a static method instantize an object where it was called?

Tags: java

```
public class Depot extends Item2
{
}

public class Ship extends Item2
{
}

abstract public class Item2
{
    public static void loadFromStream(FileInputStream oos) throws IOException
    {
        return new whatToWriteHereToGetDEPOTorSHIP?
    }
}

Depot o1 = Depot.loadFromStream(oos);
Ship o2 = Ship.loadFromStream(oos);
```

question in the code: how to create an instance of Ship or Depot from static method? Depending of Depot. or Ship.

Comment: You simply can't return something from a void method.

Comment: Why are you bothering with `Item2`? Static methods can't be inherited. Just declare the method in both classes, and write the different implementations.

Comment: @resueman static methods _are_ inherited, but they are not overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this...

```
package main;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Exam {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        Depot depot = (Depot)Depot.loadFromStream(null, Depot.class);
        System.out.println(depot);
        Ship ship = (Ship)Ship.loadFromStream(null, Ship.class);
        System.out.println(ship);

    }
}

class Depot extends Item2
{
}

class Ship extends Item2
{
}

abstract class Item2
{
    public static Object loadFromStream(FileInputStream oos, Class c) throws IOException, Throwable
    {   
        return c.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: This just ignores the `FileInputStream`. I don't think that's what they want.

Comment: I think so, too. But the clue's no more

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException triggers at newInstance()

Comment: all other sollutions seems nice too, but thats the better

Answer (score 3):

```
abstract public class Item2 {
    public static Item2 loadFromStream(FileInputStream oos) throws IOException {
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(oos)) {
            return (Item2) ois.readObject();
        }
    }
}
```

After that you need to cast. If you want the static calls you describe, create them in the subclasses:

```
public class Depot extends Item2 {
    static Depot loadDepotFromStream(FileInputStream oos) {
         return (Depot)loadFromStream(oos);
    }
}
```

Comment: this line "return (Depot)loadFromStream(oos);" doesnt result in stack oveflow? Isnt it supposed to call itself and not Item2.loadFromStream?

Comment: If you look close you'll see that the method in Depot is named differently

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
public class Depot extends Item2
{
    public static Depot loadFromStream(FileInputStream oos) throws IOException
    {
        return Item2.loadFromStream(oos, Depot::new);
    }
}

public class Ship extends Item2
{
    // ... similar here
}

abstract public class Item2
{
    protected static <T extends Item2> T // notice the "protected"
            loadFromStream(FileInputStream oos, Supplier<T> cons) throws IOException
    {
        T t = cons.get()
        // ...common logic...
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `loadFromStream()` supposed to do?

Comment: @GyroGearless Isn't that a question for OP? I'd imagine it does some de-serialization operation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of doing this without passing some information about the class to be created as parameter.

The compiler handles the following 2 calls the same

```
Depot.loadFromStream(oos);
Ship.loadFromStream(oos);
```

as this call

```
Item2.loadFromStream(oos);
```

---

Note that the `FileInputStream` could store information about the object. In this case you need to handle the object creation based on this info... (There are classes doing this for you in the standard API.)